# Is CoUninitialize required if CoInitialize/Ex failed?

Tags: winapi

I am confused by this documentation:

[CoUninitialize function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize)

> A thread must call CoUninitialize once for each successful call it has made to the CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx function, including any call that returns S_FALSE. Only the CoUninitialize call corresponding to the CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx call that initialized the library can close it.

It sounds like it is saying a successful call to `CoInitialize/Ex()` includes those that return `S_FALSE`?

Or, `CoUninitialize()` must be called only if `CoInitialize/Ex()` returns `S_OK`?

Or, should it be called regardless of the return value?

Comment: `S_FALSE` also successful status. `SUCCEEDED(hr)` is `(((HRESULT)(hr)) >= 0)` and `S_FALSE == 1`. `CoInitialize` must be called for every call to `CoInitialize[Ex]` which return `SUCCEEDED(hr)` or `0 <= hr` which include `S_OK` and `S_FALSE` (usually only this 2 codes)

Comment: S_FALSE basically means "you're doing it wrong, but got lucky, I can do it anyway".  You do have to uninitialize, it won't actually happen until it counts down the calls to 0.  In the olden days it was the simplest way to query the apartment type before CoGetApartmentType() was added.

Comment: @HansPassant `S_FALSE` means "It succeeded, but maybe not in a way you expected." Doesn't mean that you did anything wrong. For example, CoInitialize returns `S_FALSE` to say "Yeah, it was already initialized, but good for you for initializing again. Don't forget to uninitialize!" IEnum::Next returns `S_FALSE` means "I successfully returned no items."

Comment: @han Given that mental model were correct, how would library code then not *"do it wrong"*? Code that requires COM to be initialized on the calling thread, but doesn't control the environment in which it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation:

[`CoUninitialize()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize):

> A thread must call `CoUninitialize` once for each **successful** call it has made to the `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx` function, **including any call that returns `S_FALSE`.** Only the `CoUninitialize` call corresponding to the `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx` call that initialized the library can close it.

[`CoInitialize()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize)

> Typically, the COM library is initialized on a thread only once. **Subsequent calls to CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx on the same thread will succeed, as long as they do not attempt to change the concurrency model, but will return S_FALSE.** To close the COM library gracefully, each successful call to CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx, **including those that return S_FALSE**, must be balanced by a corresponding call to CoUninitialize. However, the first thread in the application that calls CoInitialize with 0 (or CoInitializeEx with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) must be the last thread to call CoUninitialize. Otherwise, subsequent calls to CoInitialize on the STA will fail and the application will not work.

[`CoInitializeEx()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex)

> CoInitializeEx must be called at least once, and is usually called only once, for each thread that uses the COM library. **Multiple calls to CoInitializeEx by the same thread are allowed as long as they pass the same concurrency flag, but subsequent valid calls return S_FALSE.** To close the COM library gracefully on a thread, each successful call to CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx, **including any call that returns S_FALSE**, must be balanced by a corresponding call to CoUninitialize.

[Error Handling in COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/error-handling-in-com):

> All of the constants with the prefix "E_" are error codes. **The constants `S_OK` and `S_FALSE` are both success codes.** Probably 99% of COM methods return `S_OK` when they succeed; but do not let this fact mislead you. A method might return other success codes, so always test for errors by using the [`SUCCEEDED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winerror/nf-winerror-succeeded) or [`FAILED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winerror/nf-winerror-failed) macro...
>
> ...
>
> The success code `S_FALSE` deserves mention. Some methods use `S_FALSE` to mean, roughly, a negative condition that is not a failure. It can also indicate **a "no-op"—the method succeeded, but had no effect. For example, the CoInitializeEx function returns S_FALSE if you call it a second time from the same thread.** If you need to differentiate between `S_OK` and `S_FALSE` in your code, you should test the value directly, but still use `FAILED` or `SUCCEEDED` to handle the remaining cases...

Comment: Thanks, I got `S_FALSE` confused for `FAILED(hr)`